# How to execute kafka-configs command inside testcontainers kafka image

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, testcontainers

I'm using [testcontainers kafka image](https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/kafka/) which is confluent cp-kafka, I need to amend kafka config using command:

```
./kafka-configs.sh --alter --entity-name <TOPIC_NAME> --entity-type topics --add-config message.timestamp.type=LogAppendTime --zookeeper <HOST>:<PORT>
```

I have an issue exucuting this command using `KafkaContainer::execInContainer` which yields no such file or directory.

I've looked at github image and confluent installation on ubuntu where it should be located, and tried various options with no success.

How to properly do this ?

Comment: Ideally you would run the actual Java API that `kafka-configs` uses in your unit tests, not calling a shell script

Answer (score 0):

`./kafka-configs.sh` assumes that `kafka-configs.sh` is available in a current directory, which might not be the case (try running `cwd` or `ls -la` instead and check the output).

But if you remove `./` before `kafka-configs.sh`, it should use the command from the PATH variable, which is supposed to be configured inside the Kafka image.

Comment: I've tried the both options with no sucess. error is `kafka-config can not be found in $PATH`